# Optimizing a query for loading message history in a chat app

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I have 2 tables, which are a users table, and a messages table

```
`users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=859312 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

`messages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `message` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `by_sender_id_and_receiver_id` (`sender_id`,`receiver_id`),
 KEY `by_sender_id` (`sender_id`),
 KEY `by_receiver_id` (`receiver_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56762871 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When a user (whose user id is 108) loads their chat history, I am currently using the following query to list all the people that user has messaged, ordered by most recent.

```
SELECT  u.username, m.sender_id, m.receiver_id, m.date
    FROM  messages m
    JOIN  users u ON ( u.id = m.sender_id
                 AND  m.receiver_id = 108
                  OR  u.id = m.receiver_id
                 AND  m.sender_id = 108 )
    GROUP BY  u.id
    ORDER BY  m.date DESC
```

When I use `EXPLAIN`, I get the following results

[image]

I am wondering if there are any obvious ways to optimize this query, whether it is by altering indexes or rewriting the query itself. My messages table has over 50 million rows.

(from Comment) The `GROUP BY` is to only select the last message from each user.

Comment: Does this query get the result you want? Because I would expect the ON to be `(u.id = m.sender_id AND m.receiver_id = 108) OR (u.id = m.receiver_id AND m.sender_id = 108)` ... and do you have performance issues?

Comment: Yes, the results are correct. The query is fast when a user has only messaged a few people, and can take up to 15 seconds for users who have messaged hundreds of people

Comment: `GROUP BY` will not work for that purpose; see the added tag.

Comment: Do you also get 15 second queries when repeating the same query? I haven't looked at implementation details of MyISAM in a long time, but conceptually, the indices should be cached in memory at some point, making subsequent query execution faster. You may need to tune some MySQL configuration parameters to ensure sufficient memory is available for caching. Last I worked with MySQL (which was long ago), the default settings were very conservative.

Comment: MyISAM caches index blocks in the "key_buffer"; data blocks are cached by the OS.  But you should really switch to InnoDB, which caches both in its "buffer_pool".

Comment: Yes, the same query is almost instant when executed again afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` criterion in the join is a real performance killer.  One way to workaround this would be to phrase the query using a union:

```sql
SELECT u.username, m.sender_id, m.receiver_id, m.date
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.receiver_id
WHERE m.sender_id = 108
UNION ALL
SELECT u.username, m.receiver_id, m.sender_id, m.date
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.sender_id
WHERE m.receiver_id = 108;
```

The above query can be optimized by adding the following indices to the `messages` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX msg_idx_1 ON messages (sender_id, receiver_id, date);
CREATE INDEX msg_idx_2 ON messages (receiver_id, sender_id, date);
```

These indices should speed up the joins in the two halves of the union query above.

Note that I dropped the `GROUP BY` clause, which wasn't doing anything and also seemed not needed.

Comment: I should mention that the purpose of the GROUP BY is to only select the last message from each user. And when I use the query you wrote, I only see results with sender_id = 108.

Comment: I think line 3 should be `INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.receiver_id` and line 8 should be `INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.sender_id` The idea of the UNION and losing the GROUP BY is a correct solution.

Comment: @XtevensChannel That requirement is very different from what you asked above, nor does your original query make it obvious that this is what you want to do.  I suggest adding sample data to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect you to want the entire thread.

Comment: @RickJames **No**, once a question has been researched and answered, we should _not_ be forced to rehash our answers should the OP want a follow up.